# Tag merge request: accounts and users

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

We have two tags:

- [users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/users) - For questions related to users, user accounts, user permissions or guest accounts.
- [accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/accounts) - Questions that relate to an area (or home directory), in which a user can store files pertaining exclusively to that user's activities

Since these tags both cover the same thing, we should really merge them. I would go with keeping [users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/users) and merging [accounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/accounts) into it.

Comment: What about [tag:user-management]? I'd add that to the merge as well